# How to select a single row multiple times in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to print 4 times the same row in PostgreSQL, how to achieve that ?

```
Table : mytable

Id   |  name
------------
 1   |  foo
 2   |  bar
 3   |  zzz
```

I want something like

```
Select 4x mytable.* from mytable where id=1
```

And the result should be

```
Id   |  name
------------
 1   |  foo
 1   |  foo
 1   |  foo
 1   |  foo
```

Comment: Do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097266/basic-sql-selecting-the-same-column-multiple-times-in-one-query-when-each-occ

Comment: @Geek Junior you can do it with sub queries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can cross join against `generate_series(1,4)`, which will return a table containing the numbers 1 to 4:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM mytable 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,4) as x
WHERE id=1
```

For each row in your original result set, there will be one copy with 1 next to it, one with 2, and so on.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, i red a lot about generate_series but could not figure out how to use it across my big query. Just tested it ! works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use `generate_series`.

**sample:**

```
t=# create table so48 (i int,n text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so48 select 1,'a';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so48 select 2,'b';
INSERT 0 1
```

**select:**

```
t=# with s as (select generate_series(1,4,1) g) select so48.* from so48 join s on true where i = 1;
 i | n
---+---
 1 | a
 1 | a
 1 | a
 1 | a
(4 rows)
```

Comment: A little bit complicated according to the multiple joins in my original query, i tried to make it simple in my example

Answer (score 0):

use `union all`

```
Select mytable.* from mytable where id=1
union all Select mytable.* from mytable where id=1
union all Select mytable.* from mytable where id=1
union all Select mytable.* from mytable where id=1
```

Comment: useful but it will make my query bigger !

Answer (score -1):

Cross join should do the job

```
Select 4x mytable.* from mytable where id=1 
cross join
(select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual )
```

Comment: it is postgres no oracle

Comment: The approach makes sense though, just need to remove the `from dual` (and the `4x` that has been copied from the pseudocode in the question).